Adding rule to the vpn table in nftables?
Using Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Trying to setup PPTP vpn server.  Getting an error with this command to allow PPTP traffic:
sudo nft add rule inet filter vpn inport { port 1723 } accept

The message says:
    Error: syntax error, unexpected number, expecting comma or '}'
add rule inet filter vpn inport { port 1723 } accept
                                       ^^^^

Can someone please tell me the proper syntax to do this correctly?

The correct syntax is:
sudo nft add rule inet filter vpn tcp dport 1723 counter accept

or (for udp)
sudo nft add rule inet filter vpn udp dport 1723 counter accept

you may specify multiple ports by
sudo nft add rule inet filter vpn udp dport { 1723, 3271 } counter accept


Thank you.  No one is using PPTP much anymore, but I need it for a project.
